# How to solve ValueError: forbidden opcode(s) in 'my code': STORE_ATTR in Odoo 17?

Tags: odoo, odoo-17, odoo-studio

I am trying to create a field using studio and compute its value.
Here is what I tried,

```
for rec in self:
    rec.x_studio_total_ic_weight = self.qty_production * self.x_studio_related_field_41o_1horg1c8a
```

In dependencies field, I added `qty_production,product_id`.

But I am getting an error while opening the form view,

```
ValueError: forbidden opcode(s) in 'for rec in self:\n    rec.x_studio_total_ic_weight = self.qty_production * self.x_studio_related_field_41o_1horg1c8a': STORE_ATTR
```

How can I resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment that way is not possible. Change it to:

```py
for rec in self:
    rec["x_studio_total_ic_weight"] = rec.qty_production * rec.x_studio_related_field_41o_1horg1c8a
```

You probably wanted to use `rec` instead of `self`, so i changed that too.